# ErrorException Illegal offset type laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

Приветствую всех, пытаюсь уже долго понять как сделать так чтобы переходя в определённые категории выводились статьи с этой категорией. И получаю ошибку: `Illegal offset type`

Это контроллер class ArticlesController extends Controller

```
public function showAll ($name)
{    
    $categories = Category::all()->where('name', '=', $name )->first();
    if ($categories != null)
    {
        $articles = Article::all()->where('categorie_id', '=', $categories->id);
        return view('categories')->with($articles);
    }
    return redirect('categories');
```

Это представление из которого можно перейти в категории:

```
 <div class="bg-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="text-white margin-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars text-white" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/">Главная</a>
        @foreach($categories as $category)
                        <li><a class="nav-link text-white" href="{{ route('articlesShow', [$category->name]) }}">{{ $category->name }}</a></li>

        @endforeach
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Поиск">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Поиск</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Это представление в которое я не могу ни как попасть:

```
@section ('content')
<div class="container margin_blok_1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-9 card margin_content">
            <h6>Все статьи</h6>
            <div class="row">

                @foreach($articles as $article)
                    <div class="col-6 col-lg-4"> <!--Post -->
                        <img src="{{ asset('upload/image/1.jpg') }}" width="255"  alt="..." class="rounded img_size">
                        <h4> {{ $article->title }}</h4>
                        <h6>Категория: <a href="/"> Продажи</a></h6>
                        <h6>Автор: {{ $article->author }}</h6>
                        <p>{{ $article->text }} </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{{ route('articleShow', ['id' =>$article->id]) }}"> Читать &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div><!--EndPost-->
                @endforeach
```

Роут:

```
Route::get('/categories/{name}', 'ArticlesController@showAll')->name('articlesShow');
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде много что заставляет сомневаться.

Основная ошибка это конечно:

```
$articles = Article::all()->where('categorie_id', '=', $categories->id);
return view('categories')->with($articles);
```

Должно быть примерно так:

```
$articles = Article::where('categorie_id', '=', $categories->id)->get()->all();
return view('categories', ['articles' => $articles]);
```

Обратите внимание на расположение вызова метода get() и all()

А вообще было бы хорошо сделать что-то типа этого:

```
public function showAll ($name)
{
    $articles = Article::leftJoin('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'articles.categorie_id');
    $articles->where('categories.name', $name)->get()->all();

    if ($articles) {
        return view('categories', ['articles' => $articles]);
    }

    return redirect('categories');
}
```

Возможно выши таблицы categories и articles называются как-то иначе, но смысл такой что теперь у нас один запрос и выглядит это всё более понятно и короче.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но ошибка теперь с неопределённой переменной:ErrorException
Undefined variable: categories (View: /home/vagrant/Code/nexta/resources/views/layouts/site.blade.php) (View: /home/vagrant/Code/nexta/resources/views/layouts/site.blade.php)